# Why wont this registry data value update?

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry, regedit

I am writing a batch script to add a registry key default value but it wont write to the value.  The value needs to be:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /dde "%1"
```

I think it has something to do with the quotation mark characters " "  but cant figure out how to make the batch script understand this needs to be in the data value.

This is what I am using:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command /ve /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE" /dde "%1" /f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Excel.Sheet.12\shell\Open\command" /ve /d "\"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE\" /dde \"%%1\"" /f
```

You need to escape the inner quotes and the `%1` that is replaced by the parser that sees it as the first argument to the batch file